# resolve folder name change conflicts bit bucket

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a master repo that contains my application. I then fork the branch to change my monolithic architecture to service-based architecture, but in between, one of the application folder names is modified and merged to master.

Now when I rename the folder in my branch and try to merge the master branch in my local branch then this error comes up

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): forgotten.php deleted in 9900eebb2cd2559043ba3e3d7a6a and renamed to forgotten.php in HEAD. Version HEAD of forgotten.php left in tree.
```

Comment: That conflict means: "They say the file is not needed anymore, but I say that it is still needed, but under a different name." Find out who's right, and that's probably the resolution of the conflict.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?